# VLC number of decoded frame rate

Tags: java, android, media-player, freeze, libvlc

I would like to know if we can calculate the number of decoded frames when using VLC for Android. I'm looking for something like that but using VLC and not exoplayer:

```
exoPlayer.getVideoDecoderCounters().renderedOutputBufferCount
```

Thanks.

I tried this

```
mediaPlayer.getVideoTrack();
```

But it returns the same value even if the video freezes!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say, but I'm going to assume you are using the great vlcj project, since you mentioned both Java and libvlc.

```
mediaPlayerComponent.mediaPlayer().media().info().statistics(mediaStatistics)
```

`MediaStatistics` likely being what you are looking for. Here is the full sample https://github.com/caprica/vlcj-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/test/stats/StatsTest.java

credits to caprica